# Adding enums, implementing same interface, to a collection throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, interface, enums, polymorphism, classcastexception

I've made an interface `Attribute` to be implemented by different Enums (as I know a Java-enum is a class actually) representing an attribute:

Interface `Attribute`:

```
public interface Attribute {
    void print();
}
```

Then I made two Enums: `Size` and `Type` with the `Attribute` behaviour:

Enum `Size`:

```
public enum Size implements Attribute {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE;

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am a size.");
    }
}
```

Enum `Type`:

```
public enum Type implements Attribute {
    SQUARE, CIRCLE, TRIANGLE;

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I am a type.");
    }
}
```

Then I test the structure within my main class:

```
public class AttributesTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Attribute> attributes = new TreeSet<>();
        attributes.add(Size.MEDIUM);
        attributes.add(Type.CIRCLE);
        for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            attribute.print();
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException` and how to get rid of this:

Exception details:

```
at java.lang.Enum.compareTo(Enum.java:180)
at java.lang.Enum.compareTo(Enum.java:55)
at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:568)
at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using HashSet instead of TreeSet

Comment: Thank you. I prefer a wrong answer; it's at least an answer.

Comment: @LowLevel why do you think this answer is wrong?

Comment: @LouisWasserman, it just didn't work.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I tried again and now it works. However, thank you once again.

Comment: I probably did something wrong. Sorry ;)

Comment: And your answer helped me actually to solve the whole problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34530898/how-to-add-different-enum-values-to-a-set-as-unique-entities

Comment: There I used `CopyOnWriteArraySet` instead