# How to add different enum values to a Set as unique entities?

Tags: java, enums, set, equals

How to prevent different enum values of same enum type from being added to a set?

For instance, I've made a Size enum:

```
public enum Size {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE;
}
```

and added two different values into a Set of that type of Enum:

```
public class AttributesTestDrive {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Size> sizes = new TreeSet<>();
        sizes.add(Size.LARGE);
        sizes.add(Size.MEDIUM);
        sizes.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

How to override `boolean equals(Object obj)` within Enum? Or what else would you do to solve this issue?

P.S. As I know enums are classes within Java.

Comment: So you want to be able to add, e.g. `Size.LARGE` but not `Size.MEDIUM`? Why?

Comment: ...and what do you want the set to contain? the first or second item?

Comment: Create either 1) your own `class` that is `enum` like or 2) your own `Set` implementation. Neither `enum` nor `Set` is designed to behave in this way.

Comment: If you want a unique value why do you use a set at all? A simple field / variable would be enough.

Comment: Dear Tunaki, I've posted two different questions because I didn't want to merge two different questions within a single topic. You've marked the other question as a duplicate, but I'm not agree with you, because the question you've point to, doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @ThomasKläger it is often useful to have a field that is `Set` like - for example `Optional` is `Set` like - it is either the singleton `Set` or empty.

Comment: You just cant override equals for ENUM. For details : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964704/why-java-does-not-allow-overriding-equalsobject-in-an-enum

Comment: If I begin to explain why I need to add one value to a set my post will become as large as my project.

Comment: @LowLevel this is obviously an XY problem. You are trying to do things with a `Set` and an `enum` that neither was intended to do - please explain what it is that you want to do.

Comment: I will edit my question.

Comment: @Tunaki I hope I could telll you why

Comment: Okay, this is now a code dump. You need to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), which this certainly isn't. We need **words** to explain what you want to do and a **short** example to demonstrate. What you have done is dump a whole lot of code with **no** explanation at all.

Comment: You are not here for explanations, but to report users. I have never understood this mentality, but keep going; you'll ever rich your goal. If it makes you happy. I'm happy too. We could make each other happy.

Comment: So - what I understand: You want a collection of data, where every single "type" of selection can be added *at most once* with *one if the enum values* as it's value. But why are you even considering a Set for this?

Comment: @Jan It hasn't to be a set. I just didn't want to make a property per attribute to make the class flexible if any attribute is added in the future. In other words, if something changes in the future I do not want to touch the class (that contains attributes). Instead I wanted to make a new enum implementing Attribute-interface. And I just tried to prevent a attribute from being input more than once, because otherwise you get a wrong HTML output. In that (wrong) case you may get <i class="fa fa-2x fa-3x"> which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a map instead of a Set?

```
Map <Class,Attribute> attributes;
```

Should do the job. You could have *one* Size:

```
attributes.put(Size.class, Size.LARGE);
```

and if you put it into a class you could even do some magic on retrieval:

```
public <T> T get (T defaultValue) {
  if (attributes.containsKey (defaultValue.getClass ())) {
     return (T) attributes.get (defaultValue.getClass ());
   } else  {
     return defaultValue;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the best solution.